# Exclude column/property from DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 w/ EF 4 application.

Here is my problem:
I have an object w/ byte[] properties (3 of them) to store files (varbinary(MAX)).  However, whenever I query the object, if those files are "large" (>1MB), I have timeout issues.  I can increase the timeout of the context, but I'd rather find a better solution.

I have attempted adding the [NotMapped] attribute to the properties, which works in that it doesn't include it in the query, but then I can't update the value in the DB.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]    // <-- doesn't allow saving, but hides from the generated SQL
    public byte[] File1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] File2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] File3 { get; set; }
```

So my question is:
If possible, how can I call

```
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

and have it actually save the changes, while the original

```
var product = context.Products.Single(p => p.ProductID == productID);
```

doesn't select the varbinary fields?

Comment: you need to move them into another object. You can create class\table ProductFiles and store binary data here and references it from Product

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Look at *Table Splitting*.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov That would work, but w/o table splitting would require a change to the schema, correct?

Comment: In my case it would require schema changes. But in the answer below you don't need schema changes. As for me it's better to store this data in separate tables, as we might reuse already existings Product data if they are the same between different products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by mapping two entities on Product table.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    // other properties ...  

    public virtual ProductBinaryData ProductBinaryData { get; set; }
}

public class ProductBinaryData
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public byte[] File1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] File2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] File3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then configure table mapping on model creation:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.ProductBinaryData)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Products");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductBinaryData>().ToTable("Products");
}
```

Note that both entities are mapped to "Products" table.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the way to go, and I have it partially working.  The only problem is, users submit 1 file at a time, and any time they submit a file, it clears out the other 2 in the database.

Comment: Would I have to create an entity/class for each file to allow 1 at a time submission?

Comment: In this case you might want to Attach your entity to the context (it will assume your entity is Unchanged and exist in the DB) and then you can update File1 field without changing other properties.